# What is the reason behind openshift error invalid ImageStreamTag?

Tags: docker, openshift, paas, openshift-origin

I have openshift server running on my machine. I am using the web console to create and build images from github repository.

I want to deploy a pod on openshift using an image that I already built in openshift. So I run the buildConfig from the web console using a template file. 
I am having this error

```
   DeploymentConfig "aliaboudkafkajava7-kafka" is invalid: 
   spec.triggers[1].imageChangeParams.from.name: Invalid value: 
   "aliaboudkafkajava7": invalid ImageStreamTag: aliaboudkafkajava7.
```

I already have a build with output image : big/aliaboudkafkajava7:latest

but this error is always showing.

Any idea why this error is blowing out ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the console or `oc`[1] to:

1. Edit your deployment config
2. Find the image trigger with: `from.name="aliaboudkafkajava7"`
3. Update it to: `"aliaboudkafkajava7:latest"`

[1] `oc edit dc/aliaboudkafkajava7-kafka`